# How can I change the values of variables in a website's JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

How can I change the values of variables in a website's JavaScript code?

I want to know because I'm building a website at the moment and, as part of the code, I have a variable whose value has important consequences for the functionality of the website. Hence my desire to know how someone can change this value (even if it only affects the website as it appears to that user).

I am particularly interested in learning how to do this in Google Chrome.

Comment: is it **your own** website that you are trying to change?  if not, it's unlikely that changing things in your browser will affect anyone but yourself;  if you are hoping to find someone to explain how to hack a website here, you are on the wrong site.

Comment: @Claies I want to learn how to change the values of variables in the JavaScript code of my own side so I can build more robust code.

Comment: how does changing the value of variables on the client make a program more robust?

Comment: Sorry, I've been unclear. I want to know because I'm building a website at the moment and, as part of the code, I have a variable whose value has important consequences for the functionality of the website. Hence my desire to know how someone can change this value (even if it only affects the website as it appears to that user). @Claies

Comment: you can't stop users from using the browser tools on their pc, so if you believe this value has important consequences, you should ensure that it is thoroughly validated on the server.  If this isn't enough security, and changing the variable is a problem for your application, then perhaps you should consider something other than a web application for this sensitive information.

Comment: knowing how they could change the value won't give you any power to stop it from happening.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by consequences but you always need to sanitize and verify the integrity of any data sent back to the server.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/

Comment: @Claies while that is good advice I'm nevertheless curious to know how people do it - hence my question.

Comment: well then you should have everything you need with the answer provided and the links to the docs that have been provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hit F12 in chrome and click on "Console" at the top, you have a fully functional JavaScript interpreter living in the scope of the website you're looking at. This means you can enter pretty much any code in the console and execute it as javascript code in the global scope of that website. Global variables in `<script>` tags are exposed in this scope, so if you have (for example) in your page:

```
<script>
var x = {'a': 5};
</script>
```

You can type in `x.a = 6` in the console, press enter, and the variable will indeed be changed.

You can even use the console to change the values of builtins, like `Array.map`, though this is not recommended as it can change or break the functionality of website code.

Comment: Dev tools do not only allow access to global variables, but to *any* variables.

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to change the variables in a script that was injected via a Google Chrome extension into a pre-existing webpage but I keep getting ReferenceError: variableName is not defined(…) - am I missing something?

Comment: The variable may be a local variable of a function. To access it, you need to set a breakpoint in the function so that the variable will be in scope.